# React-router-dom and symfony routing

Tags: symfony, react-router

I'm having an issue with Twig rendering and React rooting.

How can I use React router dom inside a twig template without having to modify the symfony routing ?

Answer (score 0):

If  i understand you correctly :

You can include and  run js(react) files in  twig ,   but to generate correct  route( as i understand  you want  to mix react  and symfony)

ypu need to use symfony routing  in js - wou cando it   by  using  https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html